# Create popup animation

Tags: iphone, uiview

How to create a pop up animation on iPhone? I want show my uiview as a popup view, like uialertview design.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600779/custom-alert-view

Comment: sorry i didnt see that question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void) killHUD
{

    [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [alertView release];
    alertView = nil;
}
- (void)presentSheet:(NSString *)message withFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if(!alertView)
    {

        alertView = [[CustomAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:frame onView:self.window];
        alertView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
        [alertView setNeedsDisplay];
        [alertView setText:message];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

You can use these functions creaed by me to show an hide the loading animation popup..

Happy Coding..