# iphone UIAlertView - custom background color

Tags: iphone, ios4, uialertview

I need to customize the background color of the UIAlertView.

I have a sample code that works perfectly on iphone 3.x, but on iphone 4 the alertview shows the default blue color.

```
    UIAlertView *alertView = 
 [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alerta"
        message:msg 
          delegate:nil
       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
       otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];

 [alertView show];

 UILabel *theTitle = [alertView valueForKey:@"_titleLabel"];
 [theTitle setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];

 UILabel *theBody = [alertView valueForKey:@"_bodyTextLabel"];
 [theBody setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

 UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"];
 theImage = [theImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
 CGSize theSize = [alertView frame].size;

 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(theSize);
 [theImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, theSize.width, theSize.height)];
 theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

 [[alertView layer] setContents:(id)theImage.CGImage];
[alertView show];
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it's most likely possible, it's not recommended to modify this type of stuff, as a simple update might break it.  Instead, try making your own alert view as demonstrated quite nicely by Nathan S.:

[How can I customize an iOS alert view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600779/custom-alert-view)