# Adding a custom pop-up in Cocoa Touch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, popup

Im trying to add a custom pop-up, I dont want to use the Alertview class, I want to make a personalized pop-up, with only two buttons, ok and cancel, and to capture those events to use them later.

Im new to objective-c, what is the best approach to do this? (a working example would be better than nice)

Thx.-

Comment: UIAlertView isn't part of Objective-C, it's part of Cocoa Touch. The language has nothing to do with it, so you'll know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few examples with projects:

[CustomAlert](http://joris.kluivers.nl/iphone-dev/?p=CustomAlert)

[Another SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600779/custom-alert-view)