# How to customize UIAlertView? Will Apple approve it?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uialertview, appstore-approval

I am using a custom `UIAlertView` with `UITextField` to get password from the user.

I have been told that this custom view may cause my App to get reject by Apple; is that correct? If so, what is the appropriate replacement for my custom control?

Comment: Why should your app get rejected by apple?

Comment: @Nick Weaver: Back in the first stages of my project, I was looking for a Custom UIAlertView With Password UITextField, the forum submitter pointed that this may be against APPLE policy because the user might think this is the Wifi dialog for network password.

Comment: Ah I see, interesting. Anyway, why don't you present a modal view which does differ from the look and feel of those UIAlertViews used by Apple.

Comment: @Nick Weaver: thanks for the suggestion,I will try those Custom views that has been tested and working on real applications now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a textfield to your UIAlertView

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"msg" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
[alertView addSubview:txtField];
[alertView show];
[alertView release];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the post, i am having ZERO problems doing that, my concerns are is that against apple policy for posting iPhone Application.

Answer (score 4):

See my [blog post](http://www.makebetterthings.com/blogs/iphone/add-uitextfield-in-uialertview/) of doing this and its perfectly accepted code by apple. I added this in some of my apps and they all got accepted. So use it without fear!!

Here is the code you can use :

```
UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your title here!" message:@"this gets covered" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
[myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[myAlertView addSubview:myTextField];
CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 130.0);
[myAlertView setTransform:myTransform];
[myAlertView show];
[myAlertView release];
```

Answer (score 2):

Check below blog tutorial for the complete solution.

[http://junecloud.com/journal/code/displaying-a-password-or-text-entry-prompt-on-the-iphone.html?cmd=success#comment3870](http://junecloud.com/journal/code/displaying-a-password-or-text-entry-prompt-on-the-iphone.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about rejection, you can always roll your own view that has animations similar to a `UIAlertView`.  Check this question out here:

[How can I customize an iOS alert view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600779/custom-alert-view)

Answer (score 1):

iOS 5 now supports this natively. Check out UIAlertView's `alertViewStyle` property.

Comment: thank you, I am aware of this new feature, I already switched to it.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

The last sentence appears to me that they don't want developers modifying the views.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a better way to solve this. Here is the code snippet

```
UIAlertView *passwordAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]                                       
                              initWithTitle:@"Enter Password" message:@""
                              delegate:self 
                              cancelButtonTitle:nil                    
                              otherButtonTitles:@"Submit", nil];

passwordAlert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;
```

(You can find related implementations in [prodeveloper](http://happy2shareuall.blogspot.in/) blog)

But this works fine on iOS 5.0 and above only. Please make a note of it. And Apple will certainly approve it.

Answer (score 0):

Ya Apple approve the customization of UIAlertview.
From iOS 5.0 apple gives alertview type to take credential input.

Here I listed a custom alertview which is able to work on older ios version and orientation
[custom alertview](http://knowledgetransferinobjectivec.blogspot.in/2012/01/customized-uialertview-to-input.html)

thanks,

Naveen Shan