# Ask user opinion, with custom UIAlertView, what's the limit to be approved?

Tags: ios, uialertview

I'm creating an app, and at one moment i want to ask the user opinion with a custom UIAlertView. After a lot of researches, and reading about this subject, i'm a little confused about some things...

What objects (UITextfields, UIImages...) could we add to an UIAlertView ?

Because i found this :

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

But this could have been accepted for example :

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"msg" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
[alertView addSubview:txtField];
[alertView show];
[alertView release];
```

(See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717292/how-to-customize-uialertview-will-apple-approve-it) for more informations)

So for example, if i don't want the blue-box with message, and title parameters, could i only do this code :

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
[alert addSubview:a_UIButton];
[alert addSubview:a_UIImageview]; 
[alert show];
```

So with this sort of code i could get the advantage (if it's work !) of put in pause mode all the app', and all would be custom. But is it possible ? Could it be reject ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend instead that you make a custom UIView, and just display that with a similar animation to the UIAlertView. Then, you can add whatever UI elements you'd like. If the docs say the view hierarchy is private, I'd leave it alone.

If all you want to do is add a text field to the alert view, that functionality is supported in iOS 5 and later using:

```
[alertView setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your help =) I want to create a view, like an alertview, but with other elements, and which block all the rest of the app'. That's why modify a UIAlertview seems to be the best way for me, but finally not. Is there any function that permits you to block all the app' like when UIAlertview appears on screen ?

Comment: What do you mean by block the app? A UIAlertView doesn't actually stop the rest of your app from running, it just disables the other controls until you dismiss the alert view. One solution would be to add your custom view as a subview of another view that takes up the entire screen, but has a background color of something like `[UIColor clearColor]` or `[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.2]` which would slightly dim the rest of the screen, like UIAlertView, and block the other elements from being tapped.

Comment: Oh sorry i thought that the UIAlertView stopped from running the others animations !! So yes i would do as you said :) Really thank you ;)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to customize "`UIAlertView`", why not just create your own custom AlertView (from "`UIView`") and add **that** as a subview when you want to display it?

We don't know if (or how) Apple might change the internal architecture of UIAlertView in future versions of iOS (e.g. iOS 7) that would break all the various customizations done to it in all the apps that have gotten away with it so far.  That's why Apple put up that warning in their documentation.

Comment: Oh ok, looks interesting. And the function that permits to the UIAlertview to pause all the app' existed or should we have to create it ?