# Animaton in UIView like Alert (POP UP)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation

I need some informative help about animation. Want to add animation in iPhone Application..
first thing is that create animated UIView like alert.. I searched elsewhere but not to find exact way.

Please help me about this issue..
There is a any blog tutorial or doc file you have than tell me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I don't wanna copy & paste*

Please see this Great Question: [How can I customize an iOS alert view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600779/custom-alert-view)

Hope you will get what you need.

Comment: Great link which you share on this question.. Seem very good this alert.. Thanx..

Answer (score 6):

Here are some effects for animations:

```
// Efects for Animation.
// 0 (UIViewAnimationTransitionNone)                                 Yes    
// 1 (UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft)     oglFlip, fromLeft   Yes    
// 2 (UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight)    oglFlip, fromRight  Yes    
// 3 (UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp)           pageCurl            Yes    
// 4 (UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown)         pageUnCurl          Yes    
// 101   pageCurl                                                    Yes
// 102   pageUnCurl                                                  Yes
// 103   suckEffect                                                  Yes
// 104   spewEffect                                                  No 
// 105   cameraIris                                                  Yes
// 106   cameraIrisHollowClose                                       Yes
// 107   cameraIrisHollowOpen                                        Yes
// 108   genieEffect                                                 No 
// 109   unGenieEffect                                               No 
// 110   rippleEffect                                                Yes    
// 111   twist                                                       No 
// 112   tubey                                                       No 
// 113   swirl                                                       No 
// 114   charminUltra                                                No 
// 115   zoomyIn                                                     No 
// 116   zoomyOut                                                    No 
// 117   oglApplicationSuspend                                       No
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And here is code for example how to use animation with `UIWebView`

```
// Begin Animation "suckEffect".
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"suck" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:103 forView:webViewContainer cache:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5f];
    [UIView setAnimationPosition:CGPointMake(300, 1)];
    [webView removeFromSuperView];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

I hope this will help you ... You can view this [article](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIViewAnimationState) to get more knowledges about animations !!!

Comment: Is it safe to use the undocumented transitions or are they considered private?

Comment: They are considered private and your app will be rejected by Apple (this just happened to us yesterday)