# Can add custom uiview to UIViewAlert?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uialertview

I have a custom `UIView` with `textfield`, `button` and `UIWebView`. I want to add this custom `UIView` to `UIAlertView` to show on Screen. Can I do that? Thanks

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't

Comment: Dont do all this , your app will get rejected by apple .please read HIG Guidelines.

Comment: Because I want to show it on Screen and disable all interaction of UIViewController push UIAlertView

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600779/how-can-i-customize-an-ios-alert-view

Comment: If you use this customize alert for your app, it might get rejected by Apple.

Comment: See My Answer Try this one. and let me know.....

Answer (score 3):

You indeed can do that, however your app will get rejected, as described in the [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) by Apple. If you still want to do that then just `[alertView addSubview:view];` will work.

I would suggest making your own UIAlertView, but with more unified design and better UX than how it would look in the UIAlertView.

Answer (score 1):

Why go for adding and showing in custom alertview .You can show it in a subview and present it using the addSubview: method

Note the purpose of alertview is to present an alert and it alone is the sole purpose.The UIView is there for the purpose of presenting it

Comment: I know but if i add UIVIew on UIVIewController, i cannot disable interaction of UIVIewController when UIView appear

Comment: Well in that case I will suggest the custom libraries like SVProgressHUD for the purpose

Comment: Can i add custom uiview to SVProgressHUD?

Comment: @HTKT611 Sorry wrong Library Use RNBlurModalView.I used it in somne of the application and works like charm

Answer (score 0):

yes,you can add,need to set proper frames and all those things like button actions on the view.

```
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"test" message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    UIView *view= [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [alert addSubview:view];
    [alert show];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code i am adding Label.

```
delegate.alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Password" message:@"\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    delegate.lbl=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    delegate.lbl.frame=CGRectMake(60, 42, 200, 18);

    delegate.lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [delegate.alert addSubview:delegate.lbl];
```

Adding like this whatever your control but only setting Frames Properly... As per your Need..